# Json issue: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: ajax, json

I have a problem with Ajax call. I get this error in console:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.
What is the reason of this error?
My code is:

```js
 function _save(action) {
    var dataObj = {
                "offer_id": offer_id,
                "user_id": user_id
      };
   $.ajax({
                url: Base_URL + "/offers/" + action + "/",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataObj,
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);
                    if(obj.action === 'success') {
                        
                            MessageBoxOK("<?php echo __('Saved successfully'); ?>");
                        
                        window.location.href = Base_URL + 'offers/view/' + obj.offer_id;

                    } else {
                         MessageBoxError("<?php echo __('Error'); ?>");
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    MessageBoxError("<?php echo __('Error'); ?>");
                }
            });
   }
```

In my controller I have:

```html
<?php

$offer = Model_Offers::updateOffer($_POST['offer_id'], $offerArr);
$view = json_encode(array('action'=>'success', `offer_id`=>$_POST['offer_id']), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: did you echoed the $view in bottom of that controller if not then add an echo $view; after json_encode

Comment: In the end of my function I have: $this->response->body($view);

Comment: use stringy before parsing i.e - - $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: It also doesn't update in database

Comment: Just replace: var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);
var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
It will surly work, I have also faced same problem and this is a fix.

Comment: It would be nice if you could set an uniform indentation.

Comment: It gave me the Error message in this way. When I click Edit - my data is there, but data doesn't sav in database. That's why I suppose , there is error with json, because action is not success. But why doesn't save? Would you like to see my full code from controller?

Comment: please give the response data here by printing console